# At least $p^2-p$ solutions to $x^2+y^2+z^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve a graph theory problem that relies on for any prime $p$ there being at least $p^2-p$ solutions to $x^2+y^2+z^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$. I believe its true but my number theory is rusty and I am having trouble proving it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: perhaps you could type in your six solutions mod 3, and summarize mod 5.

Comment: This is not true for $p=2$. Therer are the three solutions $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,0,1)$. - Also reorderings and sign changes of $1^2+1^2+2^2\equiv 1\pmod 5$ already give $24$ solutions (plus six trivial ones).

Comment: Perhaps he means the number of unordered triples $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Is it true in general for $p>2$...

Comment: @barto yes, order is irrelevant. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, evidently $p^2 + (-1|p) p$ for odd $p.$

Comment: If order is irrelevant, the formula already fails at $p=3$.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, and it's not hard to prove this answer using Jacobi sums.

Comment: @GrigoryM, thanks.

Comment: @WillJagy: It is easy to prove your formula in the case $(-1|p)=1$. In that case we can use $u=x+iy$ and $v=x-iy$ as variables. We are left with $uv=1-z^2$. If $z=\pm1$, then we have $2p-1$ choices for $(u,v)$ such that $uv=0$. For other values of $z$ we get $p-1$ choices for $(u,v)$ such that $uv=1-z^2$. Altogether 
$$2(2p-1)+(p-2)(p-1)=p^2+p$$ solutions. I believe that the chapter on Jacobi sums in Ireland & Rosen has this (for all odd $p$), but I don't have a copy.

Comment: Thanks everyone, back to the drawing board, such is math :)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I+R, Proposition 8.6.1 on page 102 in the second edition, with $r=3$ odd, $p^2 + (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p.$ So we do get $(-1|p).$

Comment: @JeromeTurner, you wasted the time of several people. Next time do some experiments before posting random guesses as though you had some evidence.

Comment: @WillJagy my apologies, I was following a theorem by Brown and misread it. Edits made, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then there is an element $i$ such that $i^2+1 = 0$, and $x^2 + y^2 = (x+iy)(x-iy) = uv$ where the map $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ is a bijective linear map.
This means that you can achieve a value $w$ as $x^2+y^2$ once for every factorisation of $w$. This is $2p+1$ times for $w=0$ and $p-1$ times for any nonzero $w$. (Counting everything we get $2p-1+(p-1)^2 = p^2$ as needed).
Thus, the number of solutions to $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ is the number of solutions to $x^2+y^2 = 1-z^2$. If $z = \pm 1$ there are $2p-1$ solutions, for every other value there are $p-1$ solutions, so in total we get $2(2p-1)+(p-1)(p-2) = p^2+p$ triplets.

If $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, then there is no such element $i$. $0$ can only be achieved with $0^2+0^2$. For nonzero $w$, the equation $x^2+y^2 = w$ is a "circle". Given one point on that circle, there is a bijective correspondance between lines through that point and the points on the circle (each line intersects the circle in a second point, and each other point gives one line passing through the two points). So there is either $p+1$ or $0$ points on a circle. Since $p^2 = 1+(p-1)(p+1)$, every circle must have $p+1$ points.
Then, we can count the number of triplets again according to the value of $z^2$ and we get $2*1 + (p-2)(p+1) = p^2-p$ triplets.

Finally if $p=2$ we have $4$ solutions $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

I get $p^2 + (-1|p) \, p.$

p=5

```
   1 :        0       0       1
   2 :        0       0       4
   3 :        0       1       0
   4 :        0       4       0
   5 :        1       0       0
   6 :        1       1       2
   7 :        1       1       3
   8 :        1       2       1
   9 :        1       2       4
  10 :        1       3       1
  11 :        1       3       4
  12 :        1       4       2
  13 :        1       4       3
  14 :        2       1       1
  15 :        2       1       4
  16 :        2       4       1
  17 :        2       4       4
  18 :        3       1       1
  19 :        3       1       4
  20 :        3       4       1
  21 :        3       4       4
  22 :        4       0       0
  23 :        4       1       2
  24 :        4       1       3
  25 :        4       2       1
  26 :        4       2       4
  27 :        4       3       1
  28 :        4       3       4
  29 :        4       4       2
  30 :        4       4       3
```

---

prime  7

```
   1 :        0       0       1
   2 :        0       0       6
   3 :        0       1       0
   4 :        0       2       2
   5 :        0       2       5
   6 :        0       5       2
   7 :        0       5       5
   8 :        0       6       0
   9 :        1       0       0
  10 :        2       0       2
  11 :        2       0       5
  12 :        2       2       0
  13 :        2       3       3
  14 :        2       3       4
  15 :        2       4       3
  16 :        2       4       4
  17 :        2       5       0
  18 :        3       2       3
  19 :        3       2       4
  20 :        3       3       2
  21 :        3       3       5
  22 :        3       4       2
  23 :        3       4       5
  24 :        3       5       3
  25 :        3       5       4
  26 :        4       2       3
  27 :        4       2       4
  28 :        4       3       2
  29 :        4       3       5
  30 :        4       4       2
  31 :        4       4       5
  32 :        4       5       3
  33 :        4       5       4
  34 :        5       0       2
  35 :        5       0       5
  36 :        5       2       0
  37 :        5       3       3
  38 :        5       3       4
  39 :        5       4       3
  40 :        5       4       4
  41 :        5       5       0
  42 :        6       0       0
```

---

prime  13

```
   1 :        0       0       1
   2 :        0       0      12
   3 :        0       1       0
   4 :        0       2       6
   5 :        0       2       7
   6 :        0       6       2
   7 :        0       6      11
   8 :        0       7       2
   9 :        0       7      11
  10 :        0      11       6
  11 :        0      11       7
  12 :        0      12       0
  13 :        1       0       0
  14 :        1       1       5
  15 :        1       1       8
  16 :        1       2       3
  17 :        1       2      10
  18 :        1       3       2
  19 :        1       3      11
  20 :        1       4       6
  21 :        1       4       7
  22 :        1       5       1
  23 :        1       5      12
  24 :        1       6       4
  25 :        1       6       9
  26 :        1       7       4
  27 :        1       7       9
  28 :        1       8       1
  29 :        1       8      12
  30 :        1       9       6
  31 :        1       9       7
  32 :        1      10       2
  33 :        1      10      11
  34 :        1      11       3
  35 :        1      11      10
  36 :        1      12       5
  37 :        1      12       8
  38 :        2       0       6
  39 :        2       0       7
  40 :        2       1       3
  41 :        2       1      10
  42 :        2       3       1
  43 :        2       3      12
  44 :        2       6       0
  45 :        2       7       0
  46 :        2      10       1
  47 :        2      10      12
  48 :        2      12       3
  49 :        2      12      10
  50 :        3       1       2
  51 :        3       1      11
  52 :        3       2       1
  53 :        3       2      12
  54 :        3       3       3
  55 :        3       3      10
  56 :        3      10       3
  57 :        3      10      10
  58 :        3      11       1
  59 :        3      11      12
  60 :        3      12       2
  61 :        3      12      11
  62 :        4       1       6
  63 :        4       1       7
  64 :        4       5       5
  65 :        4       5       8
  66 :        4       6       1
  67 :        4       6      12
  68 :        4       7       1
  69 :        4       7      12
  70 :        4       8       5
  71 :        4       8       8
  72 :        4      12       6
  73 :        4      12       7
  74 :        5       1       1
  75 :        5       1      12
  76 :        5       4       5
  77 :        5       4       8
  78 :        5       5       4
  79 :        5       5       9
  80 :        5       8       4
  81 :        5       8       9
  82 :        5       9       5
  83 :        5       9       8
  84 :        5      12       1
  85 :        5      12      12
  86 :        6       0       2
  87 :        6       0      11
  88 :        6       1       4
  89 :        6       1       9
  90 :        6       2       0
  91 :        6       4       1
  92 :        6       4      12
  93 :        6       9       1
  94 :        6       9      12
  95 :        6      11       0
  96 :        6      12       4
  97 :        6      12       9
  98 :        7       0       2
  99 :        7       0      11
 100 :        7       1       4
 101 :        7       1       9
 102 :        7       2       0
 103 :        7       4       1
 104 :        7       4      12
 105 :        7       9       1
 106 :        7       9      12
 107 :        7      11       0
 108 :        7      12       4
 109 :        7      12       9
 110 :        8       1       1
 111 :        8       1      12
 112 :        8       4       5
 113 :        8       4       8
 114 :        8       5       4
 115 :        8       5       9
 116 :        8       8       4
 117 :        8       8       9
 118 :        8       9       5
 119 :        8       9       8
 120 :        8      12       1
 121 :        8      12      12
 122 :        9       1       6
 123 :        9       1       7
 124 :        9       5       5
 125 :        9       5       8
 126 :        9       6       1
 127 :        9       6      12
 128 :        9       7       1
 129 :        9       7      12
 130 :        9       8       5
 131 :        9       8       8
 132 :        9      12       6
 133 :        9      12       7
 134 :       10       1       2
 135 :       10       1      11
 136 :       10       2       1
 137 :       10       2      12
 138 :       10       3       3
 139 :       10       3      10
 140 :       10      10       3
 141 :       10      10      10
 142 :       10      11       1
 143 :       10      11      12
 144 :       10      12       2
 145 :       10      12      11
 146 :       11       0       6
 147 :       11       0       7
 148 :       11       1       3
 149 :       11       1      10
 150 :       11       3       1
 151 :       11       3      12
 152 :       11       6       0
 153 :       11       7       0
 154 :       11      10       1
 155 :       11      10      12
 156 :       11      12       3
 157 :       11      12      10
 158 :       12       0       0
 159 :       12       1       5
 160 :       12       1       8
 161 :       12       2       3
 162 :       12       2      10
 163 :       12       3       2
 164 :       12       3      11
 165 :       12       4       6
 166 :       12       4       7
 167 :       12       5       1
 168 :       12       5      12
 169 :       12       6       4
 170 :       12       6       9
 171 :       12       7       4
 172 :       12       7       9
 173 :       12       8       1
 174 :       12       8      12
 175 :       12       9       6
 176 :       12       9       7
 177 :       12      10       2
 178 :       12      10      11
 179 :       12      11       3
 180 :       12      11      10
 181 :       12      12       5
 182 :       12      12       8
```

---

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Something like this seems to be true for the values I checked: {3,5,7,11,13} which have as minimum number of solutions { 6,20,42,110,156) which is $ p^2 - p$. We are simply counting the minimum number of times a color is used in the cube ,  though not quite what you were looking for.

For $x^2+y^2+z^2 \equiv 1 \mod p$
we get {6, 30 , 42, 110 , 182} solutions $p=3,5,7,11,13$ the minimum number $p^2 - p$ is exceeded  when p = 5,13 ( $p^2 + p$ ). So, the conjecture ( which is evidently proved below) would be the number of solutions mod 1 is $p^2 - p$ if p is of the form $4n + 3$, $p^2 + p$ if p is of the form $4n + 1$.

Here is the snippet of Mathematica code that I used: data = Table[
  Mod[x^2 + y^2  + z^2, p], {x, 1, p}, {y, 1, p}, {z, 1, p} ] where p is any prime in question, for the purposes of the theorem stated we can count solutions when the congruence is 1 mod p.